# Multi column filtering in python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering, multiple-columns

I have created a pandas dataframe. I want to filter all with the values `9, 12, 24, 18`.

df:

```
index   no1 no2 no3 no4 no5 no6 no7 
1       9   11  12  14  18  24  30
2       9   12  13  18  19  24  31
3       9   12  13  42  20  19  24
4       10  9   13  42  18  24  12
5       13  12  13  44  18  24  30
6       2   9   12  18  24  31  44
7       10  12  14  42  18  24  30
8       10  12  14  42  18  24  31
```

Code:

```
a = df['no1'].isin([9,12,18 ,24])
b = df['no2'].isin([9,12,18,24])
c = df['no3'].isin([9,12 , 18, 24])
d = df['no4'].isin([9,12 , 18, 24])
e = df['no5'].isin([9,12,18,24])
f = df['no6'].isin([9,12 , 18, 24])
g = df['no7'].isin([9,12 , 18, 24])


df [a & b & c & d & e &  f &  g]
```

Desired output:

```
  index   no1     no2     no3    no4     no5     no6     no7 
    1       9       11      12     14      18      24      30
    2       9       12      13     18      19      24      31
    4       10       9      13     42      18      24      12
    6       2        9      12     18      24      31      44
```

[original data frame and expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMyWh.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if pandas dataframe rows have certain values in various columns, scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000267/how-to-check-if-pandas-dataframe-rows-have-certain-values-in-various-columns-sc)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[df.isin([9,12,18,24])]
```

Comment: Thank you , Great help . I had to use " df.dropna(thresh=4) " to get my answer. Really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the exact answer

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'no1':[9,9,9,10,13,2,10,10],
                 'no2':[11,12,12,9,12,9,12,12],
                 'no3':[12,13,13,13,13,12,14,14],
                 'no4':[14,18,42,42,44,18,42,42],
                 'no5':[18,19,20,18,18,24,18,18],
                 'no6':[24,24,19,24,24,31,24,24],
                 'no7':[30,31,24,12,30,44,30,31]}) # Creating the data frame
df_new=df[df.isin([9,12,18,24])]
df_new=df_new.dropna(thresh=4)
df_new=df_new.fillna(df)
```

The result would be:

```
    no1   no2   no3   no4   no5   no6   no7
0   9.0  11.0  12.0  14.0  18.0  24.0  30.0
1   9.0  12.0  13.0  18.0  19.0  24.0  31.0
3  10.0   9.0  13.0  42.0  18.0  24.0  12.0
5   2.0   9.0  12.0  18.0  24.0  31.0  44.0
```